# Suggestions for making user management as quick to navigate and maintain as possible

Tags: html, css, data-tables, users

I am looking for ways to make user management on my own small sales team system as quick to navigate/manage as possible. Right now I just have a very basic table, but in keeping with my current approach in the rest of the project, rather than just call it job done, I want to consider and learn something about UX at every stage.  Currently there are are a couple of hundred user  to manage (although this is growing quickly) and each has the following data:

email | name |  password(not shown only resetable) | country/sales region | access level (manager, teamleader, salesman), list of pages they have created.

Can anyone give me some good suggestions/examples of innovative approaches for managing users that I might be able to learn from?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you focus on 2 areas for this project:

- Searchability - Users of the system will want to find exactly what they are looking for as fast as possible. Type to filter, where the filter is *< search string >* works great for searching names, as it is easy to search based on first or last name from the same search box.
- Rapid Editing - The amount of data to be added is growing rapidly, so power users will like to be able to add multiple user accounts rapidly. These users will want to do everything with the keyboard, so make sure there are keyboard shortcuts (make sure you always use existing standards for keyboard shortcuts, like ctrl + n for new) to add new users, and tabbing order is correct, fields get focus on validation errors etc. until the process is as smooth as possible. You should also have the option to select a range of users and trigger the password reset (because who wants to go click 200 buttons when you need to reset all passwords?).

I would also provide some kind of hints on shortcuts available, so that novice users can quickly graduate to power users.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Consider splitting it up into different screens based on purpose to make things easier for yourself.

Screen 1

You have the list of users for quick edits and searching. Not all user info needs to be in the column of the table if this is the purpose.

Screen 2

Detailed user screen for actions that don't require rapid or bulk edits such as editing passwords.

**Option 2**

Setting individual rows to be editable via "Quick Edit" for efficiency however you may only edit 1 at a time.

[image: example]